# Call a custom control's function in the XAML at KeyUp

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a custom `AutoCompleteBoxEx` control that extends from `AutoCompleteBox`. In the xaml, it is defined as such:

```
<customControlsPtw:AutoCompleteBoxEx x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                   Grid.Row="0"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   Padding="2,2,22,2"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                   VerticalContentAlignment="Top"
                   IsTextCompletionEnabled="False" 
                   KeyUp="AutoCompleteBox_KeyUp"
                   MouseLeftButtonUp="AutoCompleteBox_MouseLeftButtonUp"
                   ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding ItemsSource}"
                   Text="{Binding Text,
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent},
                              Mode=TwoWay,
                              UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   TextWrapping="{TemplateBinding TextWrapping}">
```

The important parts are the `KeyUp` and `MouseLeftButtonUp` for which I would like to run the functions `AutoCompleteBox_KeyUp` and `AutoCompleteBox_MouseLeftButtonUp` respectively. Normally these can be defined in the code-behind but I would like to avoid doing that, and would prefer if I could have the functions in the custom control itself.

I have the context for the custom controls defined in my xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:ptw.UI.CustomControls">
```

So I could potentially do something like `customControls:AutoCompleteBoxEx.AutoCompleteBox_KeyUp`, but it does not seem to be able to find it (Cannot resolve symbol).

I'm still getting used to WPF, so I'm wondering if there is a way I could do this?

Comment: "Normally these can be defined in the code-behind but I would like to avoid doing that, and would prefer if I could have the functions in the custom control itself" - all controls usually have some c# code for thier properties and functionality. why do you want to avoid that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...and would prefer if I could have the functions in the custom control itself

If you want the event handlers to be defined in the "custom control itself", you could hook them up in the constructor of the `AutoCompleteBoxEx` class using the `+=` syntax:

```
public AutoCompleteBoxEx()
{
    this.KeyUp += AutoCompleteBox_KeyUp;
    this.MouseLeftButtonUp += AutoCompleteBox_MouseLeftButtonUp;
}
```

Then they will be there by default in each instance of `AutoCompleteBoxEx`.